# Set namespace for my Antlr4 project

Tags: c#, namespaces, antlr4

In Visual Studio 2015, I have a project `ExpressionParse`. In the projects properties, I have set the default namespace to `Comp.Antlr.ExpressionParse`.

I then would like to set namespace on my classes according to

```
namespace Comp.Antlr.ExpressionParse
{
    ...
```

but this does not work with Antlr. I have tried to set the namespace in the **Custom Tool Namespace** but no matter what I put there, nothing happens.

To make it work, I use

```
namespace ExpressionParse
{
   ....
```

but that is the only way.

I guess I've missed out of some basic knowledge here, but I really would like to 
use another namespace. Anyone knows how to do this?

**EDIT:**
The first comment gave the (obvious) answer, thanks! Missed the `ctrl + S`

Comment: Works for me. Simply open the g4 file and press Ctrl+S to regenerate the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in first comment, thx! :)